# Why do higher frequency electromagnetic waves bounce of of smaller particles in the atmosphere but the lower ones dont?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, scattering

I assume they have more energy but what is it more deeper and clearer than that that explains it?

Answer (score 1):

You are referring to Rayleigh scattering, which models the interaction of an electromagnetic waves with bound electrons in the atoms of the Earth's atmosphere as if they were damped harmonic oscillators. The electric field of an EM wave accelerates the electrons so that they oscillate at the same frequency as the incoming radiation. However, accelerated electrons then re-radiate the energy of the oscillation, providing a damping term. The efficiency of radiation from an oscillating electron is strongly dependent on frequency. Thus the scattered power also depends strongly on frequency and blue light scatters much more than red light.